# Combine multiple selects for statistics generation into on result set

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Hey Pros,**

I am far away to have good knowledge about SQL, and would ask you to give me some hints.

Currently we aggregate our data with python and I would try to switch this when possible to. (SQL (Postgresql server)

My goal is to have one statment that generate an average for two seperates column's for specific time intervals (`1 Hour, 1 Day, 1 Week, Overall`) also all events in each period shoud be counted.

I can create 4 single statments for each interval but strugle how to combine this four selects into on result set.

```
select 
    count(id) as hour_count,
    camera_name,
    round(avg("pconf")) as hour_p_conf,
    round(avg("dconf")) as hour_d_conf
from camera_events where timestamp between NOW() - interval '1 HOUR' and NOW() group by camera_name;


select 
    count(id) as day_count,
    camera_name,
    round(avg("pconf")) as day_p_conf,
    round(avg("dconf")) as day_d_conf
from camera_events where timestamp between NOW() - interval '1 DAY' and NOW() group by camera_name;

select 
    count(id) as week_count,
    camera_name,
    round(avg("pconf")) as week_p_conf,
    round(avg("dconf")) as week_d_conf
from camera_events where timestamp between NOW() - interval '1 WEEK' and NOW() group by camera_name;

select 
    count(id) as overall_count,
    camera_name,
    round(avg("pconf")) as overall_p_conf,
    round(avg("dconf")) as overall_d_conf
from camera_events group by camera_name;
```

When possbile the result should look like the data on image
[image]

Some hints would be great, thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider conditional aggregation by moving `WHERE` logic to `CASE` statements in `SELECT`. Alternatively, in PostgreSQL use [**`FILTER`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) clauses.

```sql
select 
    camera_name,
    count(id) filter(timestamp between NOW() - interval '1 HOUR' and NOW()) as hour_count,   
    round(avg("pconf") filter(timestamp between NOW() - interval '1 HOUR' and NOW())) as hour_p_conf,
    round(avg("dconf") filter(timestamp between NOW() - interval '1 HOUR' and NOW())) as hour_d_conf,
    count(id) filter(timestamp between NOW() - interval '1 DAY' and NOW()) as day_count,
    round(avg("pconf") filter(timestamp between NOW() - interval '1 DAY' and NOW())) as day_p_conf,
    round(avg("dconf") filter(timestamp between NOW() - interval '1 DAY' and NOW())) as day_d_conf,
    count(id) filter(timestamp between NOW() - interval '1 WEEK' and NOW()) as week_count,
    round(avg("pconf") filter(timestamp between NOW() - interval '1 WEEK' and NOW())) as week_p_conf,
    round(avg("dconf") filter(timestamp between NOW() - interval '1 WEEK' and NOW())) as week_d_conf,
    count(id) as overall_count,
    round(avg("pconf")) as overall_p_conf,
    round(avg("dconf")) as overall_d_conf
from camera_events
group by camera_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to join them. For example:

```
select
  coalesce(h.camera_name, d.camera_name, w.camera_name) as camera_name
  h.hour_count, h.hour_p_conf, h.hour_d_conf
  d.day_count, d.day_p_conf, d.day_d_conf
  w.week_count, w.week_p_conf, w.week_d_conf
from (
  -- hourly query here
) h
full join (
  -- daily query here
) d on d.camera_name = h.camera_name
full join (
  -- weekly query here
) w on w.camera_name = coalesce(h.camera_name, d.camera_name)
```